# hasErrors(): how to ignoring validation of specific input

Tags: java, forms, validation, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have a User class with many variables (name, email, password, etc) and sometimes I need to update only one or two of them (using a form). I get the data from the form and use bind of a json object:

```
Form<User> userForm = User.form.bind(json);

if(userForm.hasErrors()) {
    return badRequest("error");
}
```

`hasError()` retrieves error because it doesn't receive some data. How can I tell to `hasError()` that it have not to validate some specific fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the "Forms" sample app on GitHub. It shows how to assign a "group" to your constraints such that you can enforce a different set of constraints depending on the situation. The projects I'v worked on are still on Play 2.0.x which didn't have this, but I believe it is in Play 2.1 and/or 2.2.

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/samples/java/forms

The files you want to look at are the `User` model and `Wizard` controller.

**app/models/User.java**
In your model you assign constraints to specific groups. The groups seem to just be interfaces defined within the model class.

```
  @Required(groups = {All.class, Step1.class})
  @MinLength(value = 4, groups = {All.class, Step1.class})
  public String username;
```

**app/controllers/Wizard.java**
Now when you do your form binding you pass in the group/interface class that you want to validate.

```
  Form<User> filledForm = form(User.class, User.Step1.class).bindFromRequest();
```